# Полностью отсоединить gameObject от префаба Unity

Tags: unity3d

Из префаба я создаю группу объектов. У каждого из них разные свойства, кому то что то добавляем, у кого то что то убираем. Но у всех висит кнопочка Prefab Apply, и если я её нажму - главный префаб, от которого я это беру, изменится. Мне нужно, чтобы я мог создать объекты из префаба  и между ними не было бы вообще никакой связи больше. И кнопка Apply исчезла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Unity* - не простой банальный редактор. В нем много есть своих полезных инструментов. Например в *Unity* есть кнопка в меню `Game Object` → `Break Prefab Instance`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью неё можно открепить объект от оригинала. В теории. Дальше, в зависимости от версии (не знаю глюк или нет) может пропасть меню, а может не пропасть. Лично я считаю, что просто не стоит больше нажимать кнопку `Apply` и будет все хорошо))

---

Но если надо тотально избавиться от связи и еще и от кнопок **Select - Revert - Apply**, то еще парочка способов всё же есть.

1. Проделать следующие манипуляции для каждого из объектов, которые хочется открепить:

   - Выбрать объект в иерархии. Пойти в меню и нажать `Game Object` → `Break Prefab Instance`
   - Перетащить этот самый объект с иерархии в панель проекта, чтоб создать новый префаб
   - Удалить этот префаб
   - Выбрать объект в иерархии (он станет подсвечен красным) и еще раз выбрать  `Game Object` → `Break Prefab Instance`
   - Готово
2. Можно воспользоваться скриптом, который достаточно бросить в папку `Assets`

   ```
   using UnityEditor;
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Linq;

   public static class PrefabBreakMenuItems {
       #region MENU_ITEMS

       // Полностью удаляет связь у выбранных объектов 
       [MenuItem("GameObject/Break Prefab Instance Definitive %&b", false, 29)]
       [MenuItem("CONTEXT/Object/Break Prefab Instance Definitive", false, 301)]
       static void MenuBreakInstanceDefinitive() {
           GameObject[] breakTargets = Selection.gameObjects;
           Selection.activeGameObject = null;
           BreakInstancesDefinitive(breakTargets);
           Selection.objects = breakTargets;
       }

       // Проверяет, содержит ли выбранные объекты префаб
       [MenuItem("CONTEXT/Object/Break Prefab Instance Definitive", true)]    
       [MenuItem("GameObject/Break Prefab Instance Definitive %&b", true)]
       static bool PrefabCheck() {
           GameObject[] goSelection = Selection.gameObjects;

           return (goSelection.Any(x => PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(x)));
       }

       #endregion

       #region LOGIC

       // Полностью удаляет связь у выбранных объектов 
       // Записываем в "undo" для отката
       public static void BreakInstancesDefinitive(GameObject[] targets) {
           Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(targets, "Breaking multiple prefab instances definitively");

           Object prefab = PrefabUtility.CreateEmptyPrefab("Assets/dummy.prefab");
           foreach (var target in targets) {
               PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(target, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
               PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance(target);
           }
           AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset("Assets/dummy.prefab");

           Undo.RecordObjects(targets, "Breaking multiple prefab instances definitively");
       }


       // Полностью удаляет связь у ОДНОГО выбранного объекта
       // Записываем в "undo" для отката
       public static void BreakInstanceDefinitive(GameObject target) {
           Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(target, "Breaking single prefab instance definitively");

           Object prefab = PrefabUtility.CreateEmptyPrefab("Assets/dummy.prefab");

           PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(target, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
           PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance(target);

           AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset("Assets/dummy.prefab");
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```

   Скрипт позволяет убить связь как через меню сверху `Game Object` → `Break Prefab Instance Definitive`, так и через контекстное меню (<kbd>ПКМ</kbd> на выбранном объекте) → `Break Prefab Instance Definitive`, при этом кнопки **Select - Revert - Apply** уже будут отсутствовать.